# iOS pjsip 2.2 loud speaker switch fails

Tags: voip, pjsip, speaker, speakerphone

During the call I try to switch voice from internal speaker to Loud speaker on iOS device using pjsip 2.2 library. It returns TRUE as success, but physically it doesn't change sound destination.

I use the next code

```
- (BOOL)setLoud:(BOOL)loud {
if (loud) {
    @try {

        pjmedia_aud_dev_route route = PJMEDIA_AUD_DEV_ROUTE_LOUDSPEAKER;

        pj_status_t pj_status =   pjsua_snd_set_setting(PJMEDIA_AUD_DEV_CAP_OUTPUT_ROUTE,
                                                        &route, PJ_TRUE);
        if (pj_status == PJ_SUCCESS) {
          return YES;
        }
        else
        {
            return NO;
        }

    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        return NO;
    }
} else {
    @try {
        pjmedia_aud_dev_route route = PJMEDIA_AUD_DEV_ROUTE_EARPIECE;

        pj_status_t pj_status =   pjsua_snd_set_setting(PJMEDIA_AUD_DEV_CAP_OUTPUT_ROUTE,
                                                        &route, PJ_TRUE);
        if (pj_status == PJ_SUCCESS) {
            return YES;
        }
        else
        {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        return NO;
    }
}
}
```

Could you suggest how can we make this work?

Answer (score 7):

With the introduction of iOS 7, you should now be using AVAudioSession to handle any audio management. It took me a long time to finally get this to work but I finally figured out the problem of why my audio was not automatically routing to my iPhone Speaker. The problem is that when you answer a call, pjsip was automatically overriding the AVAudioSessionPortOverride I was performing before the call is answered. To tackle this problem, you simply just have to override the output audio port **AFTER** answering the call.

To make my VoIP application work efficiently with the background mode, I decided to handle the audio routing in a custom callback method named on_call_state. This method, on_call_state, is called by pjsip when a call state has changed. As you can read here, http://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/group__PJSIP__INV.htm, there are many different flags you can check for when a call state has changed. The states I used in this example are **PJSIP_INV_STATE_CONNECTING** and **PJSIP_INV_STATE_DISCONNECTED**.

**PJSIP_INV_STATE_CONNECTING** is called when a audio call connects to another peer.

**PJSIP_INV_STATE_DISCONNECTED** is called when a audio call ends with another peer.

```c
static void on_call_state(pjsua_call_id call_id, pjsip_event *e)
{
    pjsua_call_info ci;

    PJ_UNUSED_ARG(e);

    pjsua_call_get_info(call_id, &ci);
    PJ_LOG(3,(THIS_FILE, "Call %d state=%.*s", call_id,
              (int)ci.state_text.slen,
              ci.state_text.ptr));
    if (ci.state == PJSIP_INV_STATE_CONNECTING) {
        BOOL success;
        AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        NSError *error = nil;

        success = [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
                           withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers
                                 error:&error];
        if (!success) NSLog(@"AVAudioSession error setCategory: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

        success = [session overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:&error];
        if (!success) NSLog(@"AVAudioSession error overrideOutputAudioPort: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

        success = [session setActive:YES error:&error];
        if (!success) NSLog(@"AVAudioSession error setActive: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    } else if (ci.state == PJSIP_INV_STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
        BOOL success;
        AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        NSError *error = nil;

        success = [session setActive:NO error:&error];
        if (!success) NSLog(@"AVAudioSession error setActive: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey! You are a crack! Great solution!